# Freeze table in javafx

Tags: user-interface, javafx, freeze

How can I make the table to freeze after I press a button and to unfreeze it only I press another button?

I searched for this but I found only how to freeze the position of the table.

In my program after I click on a row then the details will appear under the table. I want this to be possible only after I refresh the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you think about disabling the table?

```
primaryStage.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    table.setDisable(true);
                } else if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    table.setDisable(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Greetings Kaito